# How to save the ManyToManyField to model using POST method.? (Python 3.6, Django 2.2.)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have 3 models one is Category(Fields = category_name) and another one is SubSategory(Fields = category(ForeignKey to Category),sub_category).and another model is DummyModel.

```
# Model
class DummyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    sub_category = models.ManyToManyField(SubCategory)
```

This is my form

```
class StartProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StartProject
        fields = (
            'name',
            'email',
            'category',
            'sub_category',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StartProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields["category"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["category"].queryset = Category.objects.all()

        self.fields["sub_category"].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields["sub_category"].queryset = SubCategory.objects.all()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        clean = self.cleaned_data.get
        name = clean('name')
        email = clean('email')
        category = clean('category')
        sub_category = clean('sub_category')

        obj = StartProject()
        obj.name = name
        obj.email = email
        obj.category = category
        obj.sub_category = sub_category
        obj.save()
```

When I try to save

## Error

Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use category.set() instead.

Comment: You shouldn't be overriding `save` at all. The default implementation will do everything already. Remove that method. (Although I can't see what's unclear about that error message.)

Comment: I don't understand what "save from the template" means. But wherever you're calling save, the model form already does it for you so there is no need to define that method yourself.

Comment: @DanielRoseman So that method is not necessary. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an object to ManyToManyField when creating an instance. Have a look at the doc.

```
        obj = StartProject()
        obj.name = name
        obj.email = email
        obj.save()
        obj.category.set(category)
        obj.sub_category.set(sub_category)
```

Comment: ok that's fine, but its getting error again. when i trying to save after alteration.
**"<StartProject: test>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.**

Comment: You're getting this error because you're not saving `obj` before setting the relationships (notice above the order of `obj.save()`). But as Daniel mentioned, you don't need to do this at all. Just remove `def save()` entirely.

Comment: “I’m trying to save from the template” makes no sense. What do you mean

Comment: @dirkgroten So that method is not necessary. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you have a many2many relation between two models (i.e. A and B) you must have saved both instances of A and B before linking them through the 'set()' method.

If you only save the A and not the B to the database, that means the many2many relation will be able to retrieve ID of the A instance and not the B one.

A many2many relation is designed by an intermediary table between the two, which stores ID of both A and B in that case. If you only have 1 ID, you can't do the link.